# Second MySQL Docker container not using different port

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, docker, blogs

Hello I'm trying to run two different MySQL versions as docker containers, however when I want to connect a second Wordpress blog, I'm greeted with the error message: `Error establishing a database connection.`
In the container logs everything is looking fine and I did change the network section and ports in my docker-compose.yml, but from looking at the container information I see that the MySQL container is still using 3306/tcp as port, even though I changed it with the environment variable MYSQL_TCP_PORT: 3307 and it is using this one as well.

Running two independent setups is mandatory.
Thank you for your replies!

`docker ps`
`3306/tcp, 33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3307->3307/tcp, :::3307->3307/tcp`

`docker-compose.yml`

*Credentials are sanitized*

```
version: "3"
networks:
  test:
    name: test
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 192.168.99.0/24
          ip_range: 192.168.99.0/26
          gateway: 192.168.99.1
    attachable: true

services:
  db2:
    image: mysql:8.0.36
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    container_name: MySQL2
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1234
      MYSQL_ONETIME_PASSWORD: True
      MYSQL_USER: test
      MYSQL_PASSWORD_FILE: 1234
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db2
      MYSQL_TCP_PORT: 3307
    volumes:
      - /Wordpress/MySQLTest/:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3307:3307
    networks:
      - test

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db2
    image: wordpress:6.4.0-php8.0-apache
    container_name: Wordpress2
    ports:
      - "18888:80"
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db_dev:3307
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: test
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: 1234
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: db2
    volumes:
      - /WordpressTest:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - test
```

I did some trial & error testing using the appropriate environment variable or without it and change the port mapping.

Comment: Why don't you just map those default ports on two different host machine ports? Something like: `db1: ports: -"3306:3306" db2: ports: -"3307:3306"`? Maybe I'm bad understanding the question